# Confusion Matrix exercise

Tags: classification, confusion-matrix

everyone. While studying and working on some exercises, I found myself feeling lost and unsure about how to solve this particular problem.
[image]

I'm struggling to identify the True Positives (TP), True Negatives (TN), False Positives (FP), and False Negatives (FN). Any assistance or insights would be greatly appreciated.